# How Do I Create a Account Email Confirmation in Php?

Tags: php, email-validation, user-accounts

I am trying to send the user an email with a link (like many sites do) and when they click this link, their account will be activated. How exactly would I do this in Php?

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way:

1) Upon completion of registration, flag account as inactive (pending confirmation), and create two strings of random characters.

2) Store both strings in the database and associate them with the user.

3) Email a link to the user that has a link back to a page on your site and contains both strings.

Ex: `www.mysite.com/confirm.php?auth1=j0832r2&auth2=fji4j32ion`

4) Have your page check that both codes match, and if so, flag the account as active.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's the benefit of using 2 strings over 1 string that's as long as the 2 strings combined?

Comment: None.  You could just use one if you wanted.  I just chose an arbitrary number that wasn't 1 or 3 and was less than 4.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the section of code that I use to send verification emails.

```
//create login hash
$hash = hash('whirlpool', $user->authentication->password . time() . $user->authentication->salt);
if( !Quick_Login::add($hash, $user->userid, time() + 3600, 0) )
{
    // die
}

//load email template
ob_start();
include('templates/account_create.html');
$body = ob_get_clean();

if( Mail::sendMail($user->contact->email, 'no-reply-automator@domain.com', "Email Verification", $body) )
{
    //redirect to login         
    throw new RedirectBrowserException("/index.php?code=6");
}
```

The `Mail` class is [a simple mailer that I built](https://github.com/rockerest/myframework/blob/master/backbone/Mail.php), you can easily just use the php `mail()` function.

The email template that's loaded here is this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 600px; border: 2px solid #E9EBF6; margin: auto; font-size: 16px; color: #555555;">
        <h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 8px; background-color: #E9EBF6; text-align: center;">
            Hello, <?=$user->fname;?>!
        </h1>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; padding: 8px; padding-top: 0; background-color: #F5F6FB;">
            <p>You are receiving this email because you (or someone pretending to be you!) has signed up for a new account on the Domain System.</p>
            <p>If you would like to verify this email account (and you must in order to use the system), please <a href="http://domain.com/components/authentication/verify.php?code=<?=$hash;?>">click this link</a>.</p>
            <p>If you don't know what this is about, or you don't want the account, simply do nothing.</p>
            <p>The quick login link above is a one-time access pass to your account.  Please use the link to verify your email address and complete your account signup.</p>
            <br />
            <p>Thanks!</p>
            <p>-Domain</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The link they click in there goes to this script (`verify.php`):

```
<?php
    set_include_path('../../backbone:../../global:../../jquery:../../components:../../content:../../images:../../model:../../render:../../scripts:../../styles');
    require_once('RedirectBrowserException.php');
    require_once('User.php');
    require_once('Session.php');
    require_once('Quick_Login.php');
    setSession(0, '/');

    $code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : null;

    if( $code )
    {
        $ql = Quick_Login::getByHash($code);
        if( $ql )
        {
            $user = User::getByID($ql->userid);
            $user->disabled = 0;
            $user->save();

            setSessionVar('active', true);
            setSessionVar('roleid', $user->authentication->role->roleid);
            setSessionVar('userid', $user->userid);

            $ql->used = 1;
            $ql->save();

            throw new RedirectBrowserException("/home.php?code=0");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RedirectBrowserException('/index.php?code=9');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RedirectBrowserException('/index.php?code=9');
    }
?>
```

You'll see in that last script that it sets `disabled=0` on their account, as well as logging them in (setting `active` on their session, and assigning their `roleid` and `userid` on the session).

Hope this helps.

## Update

### This is what's happening under the hood without all the code.

1. A random string of characters is created (preferably one that is not randomly guessable)
2. That string is stored in the database, with a link to the user's ID
3. An email is sent to the user containing a link to a script and the hash (e.g., `verify.php?code=sdflnsdlknsge98y32598swob`)
4. When the user clicks the link, the script handling it checks the database for that string (`sdflnsdlknsge98y32598swob`).  If it's valid, it sets a flag on the user's account that indicates that they have validated their email address.
5. [OPTIONAL] The script can also log the user in automatically when they verify their email address.

Comment: Thank, this way looks a little complicated, is there an easier way?

Comment: Not particularly.  I'm using a bunch of objects and templates, but the underlying method is the simplest you can get.  I'll update the answer with just the concept, without the code.

Answer (score 1):

I do the following.

1. Collect their email address and password
2. Store their password as a protected hash.  I'm using PHP 7 so I use
   `password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`
3. Create and store a unique confirmation ID.  I'm anal and paranoid, so I create long strings.  In this case, 64 characters (32 bytes, bin2hex = 64 characters).
   `$confirm_code = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));`
4. Email the user the confirmation link built using $confirm_code.
5. When the user clicks the link, set a database flag (e.g., "active_user") to indicate confirmation is complete.  I do not delete the confirmation code.

OK, remember that I'm anal and paranoid.  The backend does not delete the confirmation code and every new confirmation code is checked against all previous confirmation codes to ensure it really is unique.  Why?  So people can't happenstantially use their email link at a later date to confirm an account that isn't actually theirs and to guarantee no one gets a confirmation code that was issued to but possibly not used by someone else.  (Remember, nothing is ever actually "unique" or "random" in the world of computers.  If you don't check, you don't know.)

Also, you should NEVER automatically log someone in from their confirmation link.  That's a huge security violation.  Anyone could click the link before activation and suddenly they have full access to the account.  Always force users to log in after confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have done it many times is during registration, Keep a field in the members table of "Active" being a bool (0 or 1)  0 being no, 1 being yes.  During registration mark them as a 0.  Also you will need a field of registration code.  Or you can create a new table of userid/registration code and compare it.

When the user registered, create a unique code.  Log that code and send them an email.  when they click on the link in the email, check against the table with the code and if it matches a code in the db, change the active field for that user to 1

Answer (score 0):

When they register, add a unique ID to the database for their username. Also have an "active" column set to 0. To send them an email, use the PHP [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. Have a link in the email linking to yoursite.com/activate?id=uniqueid. Fetch the ID on activate.php, do some checks, and set the "active" column in the database to 1.